# React-Admin: Clicking MenuItemLink for 2nd time clears form inputs

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

I have a react-admin based site working nicely.

Though i have an issue with the sidebar menu.  If i click one of the items twice it clears all the form inputs.  This is a link to an edit form of the resource item (in this case the current user profile):

```
<MenuItemLink to={"/users/" + user.id} primaryText="Profile" leftIcon={createElement(UserIcon)} onClick={onMenuTap}/>
```

with resource that looks like:

```
<Resource name="users" list={UserList} edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} icon={UserIcon} />
```

where UserEdit is

```
export const UserEdit = (props) => {
    <Edit title={<UserEmail />} actions={<UserEditActions />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateUserSave}>
            <DisabledInput source="email"/>
            <TextInput label="First Name" source="firstName" />
            <TextInput label="Last Name" source="lastName" />
            ...
```

on first click all the inputs are populated from my REST api, but on 2nd tap (menu item selected) - all the form values are cleared...

Any ideas?

Comment: Mind you try to reproduce the issue on this CodeSandbox ? If it's repeatable, I'll open an issue on React Admin for you. https://codesandbox.io/s/kmyk6xwjwr

Comment: hmm, certainly not immediately reproducible which i thought it would be...must be something odd i'm doing elsewhere

Comment: actually done it - something to do with using browserHistory

Comment: If you're able to reproduce, can you pass the link to your codesandbox fork?

Comment: sorry, yes - https://codesandbox.io/s/9yzr07z3ko

Comment: problem is, can't remember why i used browserHistory in the first place! Think it was due to some external deep link issue i was having...certainly need it in a cordova app for deep linking...

Comment: I can reproduce even without the custom history. Bear with me, I'll take a look!

Comment: OK, I filled a bug on the react admin repo! https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bug, I opened an issue on React Admin:

- [#2291] [Double-click on a Icon from the Menu reset the edition form](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2291)
- [#2322] [Fix resetform when navigating to same page](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2322)

A fix will be published with [`react-admin@2.3.2`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/milestone/35)!

Thanks for reporting the issue.